# Grub 'Filesystem is unknown' error on all partitions in Virtualbox Kali installation

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, grub

This morning I ran into a problem with my Kali installation in VirtualBox. For some unbeknownst reason it froze on me when I moved around in the filesystem (don't think I did anything harmful, just opened a folder). I waited for a reasonable amount of time and then powered off the machine. Next time I booted it up, I found myself in front of a grub rescue terminal where all the available partitions are 'unknown filesystems'. I have no snapshots and I don't want to lose all of my data on the .vdi.

Is there I way I can recover my machine? Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working!

My method was booting from a Live Ubuntu USB, installing [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) & letting it do its magic. The automatic repair function worked for me.